# How to use declared variables in when conditional step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, conditional-statements

I am declaring a variable outside the pipeline tags and initializing  in one of the stages inside script using readFile. When I try to use this declared variable inside when condition, the when condition always skips.

When I initialize the variable with var1='myValue' and check for 
when{ expression{var1=='myValue'} } works .
I tried making the varible into environment variable but not else works

```
def test1=''
pipeline{
    agent { label 'local'}
    stages{
        stage('initialization'){
            steps{
                sh """echo "myValue" > user_file
                pwd
                """
                script{
                     test1=readFile file: 'user_file
                    //env.TEST=readFile file: 'user_file', encoding: 'UTF-8'   doesn't work

                    //test1='myValue'   only this works
                }
            }

        }
        stage('test'){
            when {
                expression { return test1 == 'myValue'}
                //environment name: 'TEST', value: 'myValue'
            }
            steps{
                echo " user :${env.TEST}"
                //this step always gets skipped because of when condition above
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the steps under when to run, but it gets skips every time.

Comment: Your file probably has a newline character in it.

Comment: have you tried declaring the environment variable in the pipeline top level first, the using it in the stage below

Comment: That doesn't work in my case as I have to initiate the values of the variables after running some script. The above comment regarding extra line solved the issue already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt commented on the question, I had a new line character in the file. The new line character was introduced by echo by default. I had to suppress it using the -n option from echo.

```
echo -n "myValue" > user_file
```

The above command only puts the value without the newline in the file
Sorry that my shell-foo is bad and didn't realize that echo puts in a new line by default.